# Count integer values stored in List of Tuples C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, tuples

I have a function I've written that takes a Dictionary for input. It adds the total value of all integers in the dictionary and returns it as an integer:

```
    public int Total(Dictionary<string, int>)
    { 
        int result = letters.Values.Sum(x => x.Value);
        return result;
    }
```

How could I rewrite this so it accepts an input of a List of Tuples instead?

```
    public int Total(List<Tuple<string, int>>)
    { 
        int result = ?
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: your original code has something wrong, please review it. the `values` argument is for nothing.

Comment: and probably in first method not `letters.Count` but `x.Value`?

Comment: it's funny, I said `the values argument is for nothing` which doesn't mean that you could remove it, I just wanted to mean you didn't use it in your code and the `letters` may refer to some `global` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int Total(List<Tuple<string, int>> values)
{ 
    return values.Sum(t => t.Item2);
}
```

As the comment points out, you can make this more general by change the argument type to `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>>`, or even more generally, you could abstract over the first element type:

```
public int Total<T>(IEnumerable<Tuple<T, int>> values)
{ 
    return values.Sum(t => t.Item2);
}
```

Comment: maybe, just maybe, some recommendations on changing the signature to have `IList` or even `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 1):

The same as you did with the dictionary

```
int result = letters.Sum(x => x.Item2);
```

Comment: The List won't accept Values like the dictionary did. EDIT: Nevermind.